# scan a file with malwarebyte from the command line

Tags: command-line, virus, malwarebytes

Is it possible to scan a specific file from the commandline for virusses?
I use malwarebytes version 2.
I tried `mbam.exe file` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it possible to scan a specific file from the command line for viruses?

No, it is not possible

> Malwarebytes Anti-Malware 2 does not support any command line options. This feature will be added back in a future release.

Source [Common Questions, Issues, and their Solutions](https://forums.malwarebytes.org/topic/146011-common-questions-issues-and-their-solutions/)